# bar charts in percentage of the total

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to group chart in a pivot table fashion way.
I would like to chart my datas, using pandas/matplotlib in a percentage way stacked by ['post_datetime','claimed'], where the chart bar would result into a 100% divided between my True/False 'claimed' datas.

This is an extract from my database:

```
post_datetime,claimed,percent,claimed_pct,unclaimed_pct
2016,True,1.0,1.0,
2017,True,1.0,1.0,
2018,False,0.25342,,0.25342
2018,True,0.74658,0.74658,
2019,False,0.3971,,0.3971
2019,True,0.6029,0.6029,
2020,False,0.44128,,0.44128
2020,True,0.55872,0.55872,
2021,False,0.5594,,0.5594
2021,True,0.4406,0.4406,
2022,False,0.5316,,0.5316
2022,True,0.4684,0.4684,
```

So far the best I get using the following code is a next to next bar chart (I want it 100%, divided between the proporption or True and False 'claiemd', which is defined by 'percent' in my database.

```
    ax = year_claim_df.plot(x='post_datetime',
                       y='claimed_pct',
                       kind='bar',
                       color='red'

                       )
    year_claim_df.plot(x='post_datetime',
                       y='unclaimed_pct',
                       kind='bar',
                       color='blue',
                       ax=ax

                       )
    plt.show()
```

here is the chart, that I get:

[image]
But I would lile all bars to 1 or 100%, being split colored using my true/false 'claimed' column and by the proportion of my 'percent' column

I would like the chart to be in that fashion (not my data):
[image]

Tx for the help. best

Comment: Are you expecting the height of the bar (Y-axis) be based on value of `percent`, the color of the bar be based on `claim = True/False` while keeping year as x-axis?

Comment: Yes Y-axis is based on %, and yes color of the bar would depend of the 'claim' bool. I just want to have them up to each others, as opposed to next to each others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) with `rename` and then [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
(df.pivot('post_datetime','claimed','percent')
   .rename(columns={True:'claimed_pct',False:'unclaimed_pct'})
   .plot.bar(stacked=True, color=['red','blue']))
```

[image: pic]

Comment: stellar: tx v m